# I am trying to use recyclerview and cardview in my project but its giving error

Tags: android

I am not getting what actual error it is giving about .I am writing the code properly i included all the required packages and created adapter class and list class.  but still giving error. I created new one to perform the same but i am getting confused which version of dependencies i should add because i am learning app development from the youtube and udemy. They are telling to add different different version  of  the dependencies of cardview and recyclerview.

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Here is my dependencies which dependencies i should add please give e idea.

Comment: add your error message please.. so that we can understand the actual error

Comment: Please add your logs to help us identify the error clearly.

Answer (score 0):

About the dependencies, add the latest ones, basically:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
```

And like @unownsp said, we don't know what errors you are receiving, dependencies may not be the cause of your problem and this won't solve your problem.